# Wrong onDrag class being called

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, coordinates, imagebutton

I am creating an app where the user can purchase buildings that are imagebuttons that are also implementing the drag and drop API. Currently I am having an issue where say I have 2 buildings that have been purchased: colonyHutOne and colonyHutTwo. They both have their own onDrag classes and onDragListeners setup individually. When either of the buildings is dragged somewhere, the onDrag class for the second building is the one being called, (because it was the last one to be purchased and inserted into the view). I have no idea to stop this. It should be that when the first building is moved, it has its own onDrag called so that the coordinates of the building are saved for the right building, but since it just calls the most recently created buidling's onDrag class, the coordinates are not being saved correctly.

Here is the code for both imagebuttons' onDragListeners:

For the colonyHutOne building:

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutOneDrag(getApplicationContext()));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutOneDrag(getApplicationContext()));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHutOne, param1);
```

For the colonyHutTwo building:

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutTwoDrag(getApplicationContext()));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutTwoDrag(getApplicationContext()));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHutTwo, param1);
```

Here is the code for the onDrag classes:

For the colonyHutOne building:

```
public class ColonyHutOneDrag implements OnDragListener
{
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context passedContext;
Database data;

public ColonyHutOneDrag(Context applicationContext) 
{
    passedContext = applicationContext;
}//end constructor

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
{
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //drag has started
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //being dragged
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            //stop drag
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            //find drag location
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            if (v == v.findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf))
            {
                //find position where dropped
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                //save the coordinates that the building was dropped at
                data = new Database(passedContext);
                data.open();
                data.colonyHutOneXEntry(x);
                data.colonyHutOneYEntry(y);
                data.close();
                Toast.makeText(passedContext, "Going in1 -> x: " + x + " y: " + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //use this to fix building loadup glitch
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                group.removeView(view);
                FrameLayout contain = (FrameLayout) v;
                contain.addView(view);
                view.setX(x - (view.getWidth()/2));
                view.setY(y - (view.getHeight()/2));
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end if
            else
            {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end else
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }//end switch
    return true;
}//end onDrag function
}//end ColonyHutOneDrag class
```

For the colonyHutTwo building:

```
public class ColonyHutTwoDrag implements OnDragListener
{
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context passedContext;
Database data;

public ColonyHutTwoDrag(Context applicationContext) 
{
    passedContext = applicationContext;
}//end constructor

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
{
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //drag has started
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //being dragged
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            //stop drag
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            //find drag location
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            if (v == v.findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf))
            {
                //find position where dropped
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                //save the coordinates that the building was dropped at
                data = new Database(passedContext);
                data.open();
                data.colonyHutTwoXEntry(x);
                data.colonyHutTwoYEntry(y);
                data.close();
                Toast.makeText(passedContext, "Going in2 -> x: " + x + " y: " + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //use this to fix building loadup glitch
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                group.removeView(view);
                FrameLayout contain = (FrameLayout) v;
                contain.addView(view);
                view.setX(x - (view.getWidth()/2));
                view.setY(y - (view.getHeight()/2));
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end if
            else
            {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end else
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }//end switch
    return true;
}//end onDrag function
}//end ColonyHutTwoDrag class
```

Here is the onTouchListener to start the drag:

```
public class BuildingsClick implements OnTouchListener 
{   
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());

    String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }; 
    ClipData data = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item); 
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 

    v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return false;   
}//end onTouch function

}//end BuildingsClick class
```

It makes no sense to me that the onDrag for the second building is called every time even when I am dragging the first building. Please help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: You have not shown how you instantiate the drag listener classes.  Please edit your question and add this code.

Comment: @Simon I updated it. Thank you for looking.

Comment: @MeetTitan It is checking to see if the spot that a building is being dropped is an okay place to drop it (you can only drop the buildings on the bottom 3/4 of the screen) so it checks to see if the view is equal to the bottom half view. Then it takes the coordinates of what is being dropped.

Comment: @MeetTitan Sorry if that didn't really answer your questions. I am relatively new to android programming and have not fully grasped everything.

Comment: @saboehnke, I understand. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, I believe, is that you set the `OnDragListener` of `findViewById(R.id.topHalf)` to `new ColonyHutOneDrag(getApplicationContext())`.

THEN you set the `OnDragListener` of the SAME view, `findViewById(R.id.topHalf)` to `new ColonyHutTwoDrag(getApplicationContext())` after that. The second call overwrites your first, and code from `ColonyHutOneDrag` is never ran, because it is no longer the active listener.

The same problem affects your view `findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf)`.

You either want to combine both listeners into one, letting the listener decide which type of building it is, OR set the `OnDragListener` of every view explicitly. I suggest the former approach.

EDIT: This will work if your custom classes are subclasses of the view being passed. If your classes are not subclassing view, you could use a variable in one of those classes to distinguish one from the other (like a String that you compare to instead of `if(v instance of class)`).

```
switch(((View)v.getParent()).getID())
{
case R.id.topHalf:
    if(v instanceof ColonyHutOne)
        topHalfColonyOne();
    else if(v instanceof ColonyHutTwo)
        topHalfColonyTwo();
    break;
case R.id.bottomHalf:
    if(v instanceof ColonyHutOne)
        bottomHalfColonyOne();
    else if(v instanceof ColonyHutTwo)
        bottomHalfColonyTwo();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can I combine these two listners into one though? The first one is called setting the top half and the second is setting the bottom half. They are set separately because they are both shown at the same time and when the user tries to drag a building into the top, it snaps back into its previous position. This allows me to stop users from trying to drag buildings into the sky in my app.

Comment: Yes, you can combine them. You would check if the parent equals R.id.topHalf, and then allow/restrict accordingly. I would use a switch. Updating my answer with a snippet for you, check in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I gave that a shot and now my buildings just disappear when I drop them. I am not really sure how this switch will solve my issue anyways. It is doing the exact same thing I already have in there except uses a switch rather than an if else like I already have.

Comment: @saboehnke, I apologize for my oversight. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: So you are saying use just one onDrag class for both of these buildings and use instanceof to see which colony hut it is dealing with? Because I originally wrote this where it passed in a building number to the onDrag also so I knew if it was building one or two and it would still have the same problem. Plus doing it this way I will have to pass in an instance of the imagebutton since where it is created and where the onDrag is implemented are in two different classes.

Comment: @saboehnke, Yes, that would be the preferred method. What problem did you have with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67062/discussion-between-saboehnke-and-meettitan).